# jsx error:: SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in /home/meditool/Bureau/med-tool/views/register.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, jsx, ejs

i don't know why i have this error, i can't find the '/' can anyone help me please.
or tell me why this error can occurs, i spend all the day trying to resolve it ...

```
    <% include ./partials/messages %>
    <form action="/register" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
            <input
                type="name"
                id="first_name"
                name="first_name"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter first name"
                value="<%= typeof first_name != 'undefined' ? first_name : '' %>"
            />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
            <input
                type="name"
                id="last_name"
                name="last_name"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter last name"
                value="<%= typeof last_name != 'undefined' ? last_name : '' %>"
            />
        </div> ...
```

Comment: Try changing `./partials/messages` at the start to `partials/messages`.

Comment: it won't work ...

Comment: this is my messages file:

Comment: <% if(typeof errors != 'undefined'){ %>
    <% errors.forEach(function(error) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
            <%= error.msg %>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    <% }); %>
<% } %>

Comment: something is missing on `register.ejs` can you post full code of `register.ejs` ?

Comment: i can't send all, i'll do it in two times

Comment: i say that it don't work except when i add the include file line

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly the error was catched, '<%- include('partials/messages.ejs') %>' this is the correct form to include a partial in ejs.